# Como colocar icon da Font-Awesome em um botao?

Tags: html

Estou querendo fazer um botão com uma seta dentro, tentei mas nao consegui fazer, quem puder ajudar eu agradeço. OBS: nao estou utilizando nenhum framework

Comment: Pode descrever com maior detalhes por favor?

Comment: Já consegui colocar

Comment: Poste a solução então

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você vai inserir o seu ícone dentro do input, assim:
`<button> CODIGO ICONE </BUTTON>` exemplo prático(O CSS É MERAMENTE ILUSTRATIVO):

```css
button{
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:white;
  background-color:#259b4c;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #259b4c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/62e43a72a9.js"></script>

<p>Icone + texto:</p>
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> clica aqui, vai</i></button>

<p>Icone:</p>
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você consegue colocar se for uma tag `<button>`, que tem o mesmo comportamento do `input`. Ex:

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Cadastrar</button>
```